# ConTeXt center tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, context

In ConTeXt, a tabular environment evidently does not behave a centered context. e.g.:

```
\startalignment[center]
    \starttabular
        \NC item one \NC item two \NC\NR
        \NC item three \NC item four \NC\NR
    \stoptabular
\stopalignment
```

will still result in the table being up against the left side of the page. One answer here advises using `\midaligned {}` around tables to center them, but this technique seems to throw an error when applied to tabulars. What's the correct way to center a tabular block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The low-level `\vbox` wrapping aside, there are two way to achieve centered tables relying on the user interface only: *Floats* and the *frame* parameter. Floats are more powerful but even with the [abundance of placement options](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/placefloat) they might turn out to behave erratically. So the frame parameter that comes with *[tabulation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Tabulate)*-style tables might be the preferred choice in some situations.

```
%%% This is how you get a “tabular” environment in Context.
\definetabulation [tabular]
\setuptabulation  [tabular] [
  format={|r|i{1em}l|},
  rulethickness=2pt,
]

%%% Used in solution 2. Note the *align* key.
\defineframedcontent [tabularframe] [frame=off, align=middle]

%%% The table goes into a buffer for later use.
\startbuffer [demotable]
  \starttabular
    \HL
      \NC item one   \NC item two  \NC\NR
      \NC item three \NC item four \NC\NR
    \LL
  \stoptabular
\stopbuffer

\starttext
\input knuth
%%% First solution: Floats.
%%% Use the “here” key to set the float location. Try “force” if it
%%% doesn’t behave.
\placetable[here]{Centered Table Floats}{\getbuffer[demotable]}

%%% Second solution: Frame.
%%% The second solution is even easier: As tabulations respect a
%%% (undocumented?) *frame* parameter, just hook your favorite
%%% *framedcontent* macro in there.
\setuptabulation [tabular] [frame=tabularframe]
\startalignment [middle]
  \input ward
  \getbuffer[demotable]
  \input dawkins
\stopalignment

\stoptext
```

[image: centered tabulation]

**EDIT** As Marco pointed out, the framed version will suppress page breaks. In case your tabulations get too long, you will have to resort to the first version (float, with the *split* option). Or you can just create a *narrower* environment that centers the table according to its width. In below listing this is done inside the macro `\centertabulation` which takes the table as an argument.

```
\newdimen\current_tabulation_offset

\def\test_hsize#1{
  \setbox0\vbox{#1}%
  \current_tabulation_offset\dimexpr(\hsize-\wd0)/2
}

\definenarrower [tabulate_narrower]
\setupnarrower  [tabulate_narrower] [
  middle=\current_tabulation_offset,
]
\def\centertabulation#1{
  \test_hsize{#1}%
  \starttabulate_narrower
    #1%
  \stoptabulate_narrower
}

\protect

\starttext

\startalignment [middle]
  \input ward
  \centertabulation{\getbuffer[demotable]}
  \input ward
\stopalignment

\stoptext
```

Beware that this approach will misalign all horizontal rules in the table.

Comment: The frame prevents the `tabular` from being broken across pages.

Comment: I’d prefer floats with long tables. But I added an alternative that avoids floats anyways.

Comment: It is better to use `here,force` to ensure that the floats don't float.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the canonical way to force centering, but the following should work

```
\startalignment[middle]
\dontleavehmode
\vbox{%                                                                         
\starttable[|l|l|]
  \NC item one \NC item two \NC\NR
  \NC item three \NC item four \NC\NR
\stoptable
}
\stopalignment
```

The `\dontleavehmode` command is often used with `\startalignment`, see e.g. Context help on [Command/startalignment](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startalignment). The `\vbox` trick is something I found on Context mailing.