# Set the width of every columns of a table in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, context, columns

Sometimes, I need such a table whose column widths should be equal with each other. Here is an example:

```
Name    Email
John    john1989@gmail.com
Bill    bill1990@outlook.com
Tim     tim1995@hotmail.com
```

The Name Column should flushed right and the Email Column should be flushed left. Of course, each column has the same width.

I think this requirement can be achieved by the `\starttable` and `\stoptable`, but how to combine the `l` or `r` with the required width?

Comment: Use `\starttable[|lw(4cm)r|lw(7cm)]`. A small list of references are given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2839/where-can-i-find-good-context-documentation/2938#2938

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\starttable` syntax is deprecated and should thus be avoided for new
documents. That's why I present a solution using natural tables, also
called HTML tables. Since natural tables are very verbose they can be best
combinded with the `database` module. That allows very easy and readable
syntax, but is less flexible. It depends on your requirements if the
`database` module makes sense in this case. The natural table setup is the
same in both cases.

For more simple tasks the tabulate tables might be sufficient.

```
\usemodule [database]

\defineseparatedlist
  [NaturalTable]
  [separator=comma, %% not necessary, already the default
   before=\bTABLE, after=\eTABLE,
   first=\bTR, last=\eTR,
   left=\bTD, right=\eTD,
   setups=s:NaturalTable]

\startsetups [s:NaturalTable]
  \setupTABLE              [frame=off, distance=5mm]
  \setupTABLE [column] [1] [width=2cm, align=flushright]
  \setupTABLE [row]    [1] [style=bold]
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startNaturalTable
  Name, Email
  John, john1989@gmail.com
  Bill, bill1990@outlook.com
  Tim , tim1995@hotmail.com
\stopNaturalTable

\starttabulate [|p(3cm)r|l|]
  \NC Name \NC Email                \AR
  \NC John \NC john1989@gmail.com   \AR
  \NC Bill \NC bill1990@outlook.com \AR
  \NC Tim  \NC tim1995@hotmail.com  \AR
\stoptabulate


\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: by the way, how can I center the table created by `\starttabulate` and `\stoptabulate`? I have tried `\startalignment[middle]` and `\stopalignment`, but nothing happened.

Comment: I use the plain TeX method `\hbox to\hsize{\vbox{\starttabulate...\stoptabulate}}`. This won't be broken across pages, is there another way by which the table can span pages?

Comment: That's tricky with tabulate. The easiest (but ugly) way is to use something like `\starttabulate[|p(.4\textwidth)|l|]`. For a more automatic solution see [Philipps `\centertabulation` macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54502/5245).